# Refresh PHP data array without reloading page

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm trying to create a four-answer quiz using SQL & PHP.  I can put the answers into an array and then shuffle them, but then I need to pull in another question plus answers from the database without reloading the page (to keep track of scores).

Could anyone provide a method for being able to download the new data and place it through the array again to be shuffled for output, please?

Here's my code:

```
$query = '
            SELECT * FROM quiz
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 1;
            ';

        $getQuizInfo = $conn->query($query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getQuizInfo)) {

            $answers = array
                (
                    array($row['a1'],"CORRECT"),
                    array($row['a2'],"WRONG"),
                    array($row['a3'],"WRONG"),
                    array($row['a4'],"WRONG")
                );
            shuffle($answers);

            $quiz = '
                <div class="questionContainer">
                    <div class="questionBox">'.$questionNumber.'.&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row["question"].'</div>
                </div>
                <div class="answerContainer">
                    <div class="answerBox">
                        <div class="answer">
                        '.$answers[0][0].'
                        </div>
                            <div class="circle">1</div>
                        <div class="answerSlider">
                        '.$answers[0][1].'
                            <div class="slideEnd"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="answerBox">
                        <div class="answer">
                        '.$answers[1][0].'
                        </div>
                            <div class="circle">2</div>
                        <div class="answerSlider">
                        '.$answers[1][1].'
                            <div class="slideEnd"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="answerBox">
                        <div class="answer">
                        '.$answers[2][0].'
                        </div>
                            <div class="circle">3</div>
                        <div class="answerSlider">
                        '.$answers[2][1].'
                            <div class="slideEnd"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="answerBox">
                        <div class="answer">
                        '.$answers[3][0].'
                        </div>
                            <div class="circle">4</div>
                        <div class="answerSlider">
                        '.$answers[3][1].'
                            <div class="slideEnd"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quizScoreContainer">
                        <div class="quizScore">0</div><br>
                        <div class="quizScore">15</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
            echo $quiz;
```

Comment: Javascript and XHR.

Comment: ButtonClick and ajax request may solve your problem